# parse background job each() does not go through all records?

Tags: parse-platform

I wrote a cloud job to insert a lowercase version of a user's first name and last name in the user object so that I can perform a search from my client app.

When I did run this job on a dev parse app that had like 40 users it worked great.

When I did run this on my production app however it did not update all of my records. I  have a few thousands users at the moment and I was expecting this cloud job to take care of all of them as explained here:

http://blog.parse.com/2013/05/13/launch-and-iterate-parse-data-migrations/

**" The new each method on Parse.Query objects allows you to do just that. Even if you have tens of thousands of objects or more in a collection, it will return each one of them, giving you an opportunity to modify them as you see fit."**

So then my question is why does this function leave behind over half of my database? It only worked on a bunch of users, maybe a few hundred.

How can I make this function affect my WHOLE DATASET in the User table?

```
Parse.Cloud.job("migration1", function(request, status) {
  // Set up to modify user data
  Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
  // Query for all users
  var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
  query.each(function(user) {
      // Set and save the change
      var firstname = user.get("firstname");
      if(firstname) {
        user.set("searchfirstname", firstname.toLowerCase());   
      } else {
        user.set("searchfirstname", "");    
      }
      var lastname = user.get("lastname");
      if(lastname) {
        user.set("searchlastname", lastname.toLowerCase()); 
      } else {
        user.set("searchlastname", ""); 
      }
      return user.save();
  }).then(function() {
    // Set the job's success status
    status.success("search migration completed successfully.");
  }, function(error) {
    // Set the job's error status
    status.error("Uh oh, something went wrong with search migration");
  });
});
```

EDIT:
Ok so when I look at the error logs I see this:

```
E2014-10-18T15:48:49.984Z] v63: Ran job searchMigration with:
  Input: {}
  Failed with: TypeError: Cannot call method 'toLowerCase' of undefined
```

I tried to check for undefined in any way I could think of and I still get the same problem.
What I tried to check for undefined is this:

```
if(lastname === undefined  || lastname === void 0 || typeof lastname == 'undefined') ...
```

I still get the toLowerCase of undefined error and I think that is why the job does not affect all of my user table since it stops...

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I finally figured out why the job did not go through all the records but it would stop after a few records "randomly"...

I had an AfterSave hook for the user which was triggered at each iteration of the above job...
In that after save it would generate an error at times and make the Job fail.

So, for some reason I thought the after save hook would have not been triggered by a save done on the user while inside of a Job.

That's it. Now it all works.